# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Method is only allowed for a query

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have used the following code to run a query on my database.

```
@Repository
public interface PurchaseOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<PurchaseOrder, PurchaseOrderID> {

    @Query(value ="update PURCHASE_ORDER   set status='REJECTED'   where id=?1", nativeQuery = true)
    void RejectPO(Long id);
}
```

and then i simply call this method in a service

```
@Service
public class SalesService {

    @Autowired
    PurchaseOrderRepository purchaseOrderRepository;
public void RejectPurchaseOrder(Long of) {

        purchaseOrderRepository.RejectPO(of);
    }
}
```

but i face with an error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Method is only allowed for a query. Use execute or executeUpdate instead of executeQuery; SQL statement:
update PURCHASE_ORDER   set status='REJECTED'   where id=? [90002-191]
```

The problem is, i have never called `executeQuery`, i just ask to run it using `jpa`. So how can i fix it?

Comment: May I ask @Jeff that if the answer solved your issue, can you accept it as the correct answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

In order for JPA to actually run custom @Query which modifies state of the database, the method has to be annotated with @Modifying to tell JPA to use executeUpdate etc.

Instead of

```
@Query(value ="update PURCHASE_ORDER   set status='REJECTED'   where id=?1", nativeQuery = true)
void RejectPO(Long id);
```

Try

```
@Modifying
@Query(value ="update PURCHASE_ORDER   set status='REJECTED'   where id=?1", nativeQuery = true)
void RejectPO(Long id);
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries for details.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this line:

```
 // Used only when select statement is used .
 @Query(value ="update PURCHASE_ORDER   set status='REJECTED'   where id=?1", nativeQuery = true)
    void RejectPO(Long id);
```

You are trying to `update` the schema, but you're using only the `@Query` annotation.

When a query method is annotated with `@Query` only, internally Spring calls `executeQuery()` which is not used to `modify` the values in a Schema. `executeQuery()` is only responsible for executing `select` queries.

Add one more annotation which enables your `@Query` to update:

```
 @Modifying  // add this annotation
 @Query(value ="update PURCHASE_ORDER   set status='REJECTED'   where id=?1", nativeQuery = true)
    void RejectPO(Long id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException message because you are not applying the @Modifying annotation to the repository method `void RejectPO(Long id);`. 
This should definitely fix the issue :

```
@Modifying
@Query(value ="update PURCHASE_ORDER   set status='REJECTED' where id=?1", nativeQuery = true)
void RejectPO(Long id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here

```
 @Repository
public interface PurchaseOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<PurchaseOrder, PurchaseOrderID> {

    @Query(value ="update PURCHASE_ORDER   set status='REJECTED'   where id=?1", nativeQuery = true)
    void RejectPO(Long id);
}
```

I added @Transactional & @Modifying to my interface like this and it worked

```
 @Transactional
 @Repository
 public interface PurchaseOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<PurchaseOrder, PurchaseOrderID> {
    @Modifying
    @Query(value ="update PURCHASE_ORDER   set status='REJECTED'   where id=?1", nativeQuery = true)
    void RejectPO(Long id);
}
```

Hope it should help